# Javascript modal to crop existing images ? how to iterate through list of modals with js function to handle them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, cropperjs

I have a page that has multiple images uploaded by user and user could select a part of these images to submit in a form ( just the coordinates x,y,h,w ) so I made a modal for every image but my problem is with the javascript function as it doesn't trigger the modal to show and I'm not really familiar with javascript yet.

basically when i click the button i want a modal to open and preview the image.

I use `cropper.js` to grab the cropping data and it loaded successfully when I tried it on a regular file upload form where there was one form in the page and the modal was triggered by the file field but now I want to use it with already existing image.

the images list:

```
 <div class="row">
 {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
   <div class="col-md-4 img-box">
       <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
             <a href="{{ image.pre_analysed.url }}" data-lightbox="patient's images" >
                 <img src="{{ image.pre_analysed.url }}" class="img-thumbnail" id="img{{image.pk}}" >
                    </a>
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                     <div class="btn-group">
                                  {% endif %}
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="{%url 'patients:image_crop' pk=image.pk %}" id="formUpload{{image.pk}}">
          <input type="hidden" name="x" id="id_x{{image.pk}}">
          <input type="hidden" name="y" id="id_y{{image.pk}">
          <input type="hidden" name="width" id="id_width{{image.pk}">
          <input type="hidden" name="height" id="id_height{{image.pk}">
                 </form>
                 <button type ="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-defaul" id="crop{{image.pk}}">Crop</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

and the modal

```
 {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalCrop{{image.pk}}">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Crop the photo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="image{{image.pk}}" style="max-width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-group pull-left" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-in">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default js-zoom-out">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Nevermind</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-crop-and-upload">Crop and upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    {% endfor %}
```

and the function to trigger the modal crop:

```
 $(function () {

     {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
      /* SCRIPT TO OPEN THE MODAL WITH THE PREVIEW */
      $("#crop{{image.pk}}").click(function () {
            var img_src = document.getElementById("img{{image.pk}}").src
            $("#image{{image.pk}}").attr("src", img_src);
            $("#modalCrop{{image.pk}}").modal("show");
          }
      });
    {% endfor %}

     {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
      /* SCRIPTS TO HANDLE THE CROPPER BOX */
      var $image = $("#image{{image.pk}}");
      var cropBoxData;
      var canvasData;
      $("#modalCrop{{image.pk}}").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        $image.cropper({
          viewMode: 1,
          aspectRatio: 1/1,
          minCropBoxWidth: 200,
          minCropBoxHeight: 200,
          ready: function () {
            $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
            $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
          }
        });
      }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        cropBoxData = $image.cropper("getCropBoxData");
        canvasData = $image.cropper("getCanvasData");
        $image.cropper("destroy");
      });

      $(".js-zoom-in").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
      });

      $(".js-zoom-out").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
      });
    {% endfor %}

     {% for image in Patient_detail.images.all %}
      /* SCRIPT TO COLLECT THE DATA AND POST TO THE SERVER */
      $(".js-crop-and-upload").click(function () {
        var cropData = $image.cropper("getData");
        $("#id_x{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["x"]);
        $("#id_y{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["y"]);
        $("#id_height{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["height"]);
        $("#id_width{{image.pk}}").val(cropData["width"]);
        $("#formUpload{{image.pk}}").submit();
      });
    {% endfor %}

    });
```

I use django template syntax to iterate through the image and assigning the pks.
and I get in the console

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Update1:

I made the modal show up but the cropping box didn't show here's what i changed. I made the button `data-toggle` to `modal` and made the `data-target` to the modal `id` and removed the function that handles the modal.

```
 <button type ="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-defaul" id="crop{{image.pk}}" data-toggle="modal"
                                          data-target="#modalcrop{{ image.pk }}">Crop</button>
```

and now the error message doesn't show in the console. but i get this now

> ReferenceError: $image is not defined